# Why is the "Select" of a Method Syntax is in another parenthesis?

Tags: linq, lambda

```
var sample = db.Database.OrderByDescending(x => x.RecordId).Select(y => y.RecordId).FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't know if my title is `correct / right`. Just want to ask why this query the select is in another `( )`?. As for the example `.Select(y => y.RecordId)` unlike the query I use to be

`var sample = (from s in db.Databse where s.RecordId == id select s)` I know this is the same right?. Then what is the why it is in another parenthesis?. Anyone has an idea or can anyone explain it why?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, the two queries are different. The first _orders_ by `RecordId`, then projects the sequence to `RecordId`s and then takes the first one of those `RecordId`s. The second query takes only elements with matching `RecordId` but returns a sequence of complete records, not only `RecordId`s. These are completely different queries.

Comment: ow sorry then my query must be `select s.RecordId` then?

Comment: Your first example uses the syntax of [Linq To Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964(v=vs.110).aspx), the second example uses the syntax required by [Linq to Sql](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-linq-to-sql-part-1)

Comment: @Steve: No, that's not true at all. Both kinds of syntax are fine with any kind of LINQ. Query expressions are simply translated into non-query-expression syntax by the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, you're using "regular" C# syntax to call a bunch of extension methods:

```
var sample = db.Database
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.RecordId)
               .Select(y => y.RecordId)
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

(They happen to be extension methods here, but of course they don't have to be...)

You use lambda expressions to express how you want the ordering and projection to be performed, and the compiler converts those into expression trees (assuming this is EF or similar; it would be delegates for LINQ to Objects).

The second example is a *query expression*, although it doesn't actually match your first example. A query expression corresponding to your original query would be:

```
var sample = (from x in db.Database
              orderby x.RecordId descending
              select x.RecordId)
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

Query expressions are very much syntactic sugar. The compiler effectively converts them into the first form, then compiles that. The *range variable* declared in the `from` clause (`x` in this case) is used as the parameter name for the lambda expression, so `select x.RecordId` becomes `.Select(x => x.RecordId)`.

Things become a bit more complicated with joins and multiple `from` clauses, as then the compiler introduces *transparent identifiers* to allow you to work with all the range variables that are in scope, even though you've really only got a single parameter. For example, if you had:

```
var query = from person in people
            from job in person.Jobs
            order by person.Name
            select new { Person = person, Job = job };
```

that would be translated into the equivalent of

```
var query = people.SelectMany(person => person.Jobs, (person, job) => new { person, job } )
                  .OrderBy(t => t.person.Name)
                  .Select(t => new { Person = t.person, Job = t.job });
```

Note how the compiler introduces an anonymous type to combine the `person` and `job` range variables into a single object, which is used later on.

Basically, query expression syntax makes LINQ easier to work with - but it's just a translation into other C# code, and is neatly wrapped up in a single section of the C# specification. (Section 7.16.2 of the C# 5 spec.)

See my [Edulinq blog post on query expressions](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/) for more detail on the precise translation from query expressions to "regular" C#.

Comment: I would like to ask cuz i dont have any knowledge in lambda. Can this bi possible? `(x => x.RecordId Select y => y.RecordId)`.

Comment: @Broow: No. That's simply not valid C#.

Comment: Ow I see Thanks. I'm just starting to read on how to use / learn about lambda expression but i guess its difficult :)

Comment: @Broow: It's not particularly difficult, but you need to separate it mentally from query expressions, which are *translated* into lambda expressions, but shouldn't be confused with them.

Comment: maybe I need a longer time to study it before using it in my daily routine codes.